# Erro na totalização de um lista utilizando Hash Map

Tags: java

Eu classifico uma lista em determinada ordem, depois crio um Map para totalizar essa lista agrupando por uma chave.

O que acontece é que algumas vezes os valores são ignorados gerando diferença no total. E não consigo ver onde isso pode estar ocorrendo veja o codigo:

```
// Classifica

listaLancamentos.sort(new OrdenaVolumeProdutoPorNome().thenComparing(new       OrdenaVolumeProdutoVariedadePorNome()).thenComparing(new OrdenaVolumeProdutoPorUf())
                .thenComparing(new OrdenaVolumeProdutoPorMunicipio()));

        // Totaliza volumes

        Map<String, DtoVolumeProduto> map = new HashMap<String, DtoVolumeProduto>();

        for (DtoVolumeProduto dvl : listaLancamentos) {
            String key = dvl.getNmProduto()+" "+dvl.getNmProdutoVariedade()+" "+dvl.getSgUf()+" "+dvl.getNmMunicipio();
            if (!map.containsKey(key)) {

                map.put(dvl.getNmProduto()+" "+dvl.getNmProdutoVariedade()+" "+dvl.getSgUf()+" "+dvl.getNmMunicipio(), dvl);
                // logger.info(key+" - "+dvl.getVolumeKg()+" "+dvl.getPrecoMedioKg()+"
                // "+dvl.getVrTotal());

            } else {
                DtoVolumeProduto dto = map.get(key);

                // logger.info(key+" "+dvl.getVolumeKg());

                BigDecimal volumeKg = dto.getVolumeKg().setScale(3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).add(dvl.getVolumeKg().setScale(3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
                dto.setVolumeKg(volumeKg);  
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom pessoal,  agradeço a todos que ao menos olharam a questão. Mas todo esse processo está ok e calculando corretamente. Depois de vários testes descobri que a origem de problema se dava na lista de origem que vinha com duplicações bastou colocar

Antes:

return criteria.list();

Agora:

return criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).addOrder(Order.desc("id")).list();

Feito isso todos os calculos bateram com performance excepcional para volumes de dados significativos.

Abs